# GRUB2 fails sometimes on USB bootable disk

Tags: grub2

I have a USB disk which I use for backing up various laptops/servers at the office (bare metal backup).  The USB disk has grub 2 installed, with CentOS7.

I created the USB disk with CentOS7 on a computer with no SATA hard disks - just the USB hard disk.  I can then boot that computer no problem.

However, if I plug that USB disk into computers with 1,2, or 3 SATA hard disks it will not boot.  (Grub2 says BOOTMGR missing error, rescue error, or similar).  Grub2 starts (from MBR) but then has problems.

Does this mean that Grub2 has hard-coded the boot partition name (`/dev/sda1` or `/dev/sb1` etc.) into the MBR?  So I cannot boot a system with a different number of hard disks?  (The USB disk will always be assigned a drive number higher than internal disks)

Is there a way to force Grub2 to look for the boot partition regardless of drive number?

Comment: It does sound like a bad grub configuration.  You should make it select the drive by UUID.  For assistance, you'll need to show us its configuration so we can guide you in fixing it.

Comment: Grub2 doesn't go so far as showing the boot menu (from grub.conf) so I don't think that would help.  Somehow the bootload on the MBR is not able to find the grub.conf.  Or is there some other file I should show?

Comment: If you don't get the Grub menu, then it's probably BIOS/UEFI related.

Comment: One 6 different systems?  All of which boot a USB device fine?  Doesn't seem right

Comment: Do these 6 systems use UEFI?  https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Grub2 may be of help if that's the case.

Comment: 1 does, all others legacy BIOS.  Somehow the bootloader in the MBR seems to be looking at /dev/sda1 (used during setup), but needs to look at /dev/sdb1 or /dev/sdc1 depending on which system is being booted.  I'm trying to figure out if/how to force bootloader to look at the right disk

Comment: The part you're talking about with the wrong device to use for boot and root files is why I initially mentioned using UUID.  This would not prevent you from seeing the grub menu which will become visible if the host tries to boot from it, even if the rest of the configuration is bad.

Comment: The grub.conf entries (including UUID reference) only applies if Grub2 gets as far as reading the grub.conf file.  It's not.  This is MBR related.

Comment: Is it perhaps possible that the machine it does boot on loads it through a boot loader on one of its disks?